# Calculate percentage of win attempts in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas `DataFrame` and I am trying to solve a small lottery exercise. I would like to calculate the percentage of persons who won `nth` attempt (1st attempt, 2nd attempt, 3rd attempt, and so on...). For some reason I am getting total percentage above 100%. Not sure why...  Can anyone spot the problem?

Input:

```
| person | result |
|--------|--------|
| a      | loss   |
| b      | win    |
| a      | loss   |
| c      | loss   |
| d      | loss   |
| c      | loss   |
| c      | win    |
| d      | win    |
```

Expected output:

```
Percentage of people who won on their attempt 1: 25.00% # Person B
Percentage of people who won on their attempt 2: 25.00% # Person D
Percentage of people who won on their attempt 3: 25.00% # Person C
```

```
attempts_per_person = data.groupby('person').count()

max_attempts = 3 # I only care about first 3 attempts for now

res = []
for i in range(max_attempts):
    num_wins = data.loc[data.groupby('person').cumcount() == i, 'result'].eq('win').sum()
    res.append((num_wins / attempts_per_person.shape[0]) * 100)

for i, pct in enumerate(res):
    print(f"Percentage of people who won on their attempt {i+1}: {pct:.2f}%")
```

Comment: `attempts_per_person.shape[0]` makes no sense since here `shape[0]` will always be 4 (as you only have 4 people)

Comment: `shape[0]` is supposed to return the total number of attempts per person

Comment: This is correct but you can't use `shape[0]` to get counts. It is defined as `attempts_per_person = data.groupby('person').count()` which will return `pd.Series(data=[2, 1, 3, 2], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])` where indices are unique persons (grouping variable) and values are counts for each of the persons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try pivot the table:

```
(df.assign(attempt=lambda x: x.groupby('person').cumcount().add(1), 
           won=df['result'].eq('win'))
   .pivot_table(index='person', columns='attempt', values='won', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
   .add_prefix('win at ')
   .mean()
)
```

Output:

```
attempt
win at 1    0.25
win at 2    0.25
win at 3    0.25
dtype: float64
```

The reason you don't get 100% is that in your data, `a` never wins. If you include these person, you would get sum to `1`.

Comment: What is the use of `mean` here?

Comment: `mean` counts the number of `1` (win) in the columns, then divide that by the number of people. Remove the `mean` and run the code to see the result before taking mean.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75871888/calculate-percentage-of-persons-who-won-lottery-nth-attempt-after-a-loss-in-py? It's a follow-up question on the problem you solved. I'm bit lost on how to solve it...